# How to choose the agents that have different value in the set

Tags: netlogo

I would like to change the value of the variable `my-inventory-slot` of a set of agents but only in the case that value is not repeated (i.e. his value is unique in the set).

```
breed [ tags tag ]
tags-own [ my-inventory-slot inventoried? ]
breed [ readers reader ]
```

and

and I have tested

```
ask my-tags with [ my-inventory-slot != [my-inventory-slot] of self ] [
      set inventoried? true
      set color red
  ]
```

where `my-tags`is a reader variable containing the tags around the reader.

The problem is in the selection `with [ my-inventory-slot != [my-inventory-slot] of self ]` because I have try `my-inventory-slot = 5` and the code works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATED

```
let thistag  [ my-inventory-slot ] of one-of my-tags 
ask tags with [ my-inventory-slot != thistag ] [
      set inventoried? true
      set color red
  ]
```

UPDATED AGAIN - after downloading code

This is the code that calls the problem procedure:

```
to go
  ask reader 0 [
    setup-inventory-in-frame
    one-frame-inventory
  ]
end
```

So a `reader` is being asked to run the code. However, readers do not have a variable `my-inventory-slot`, this is a variable belonging to the `tags` breed. This is your problem, you need to work out the connection between the reader running the code and the `my-inventory-slot` variable that you want the match to.

From the chat discussion, what you actually want is the tags belonging to the reader (that is, the variable my-tags) that have unique values of my-inventory-slot. I think this code will do that:

```
to one-frame-inventory
  let frame-time 0
  let unique-tags my-tags
  let forward-list [ my-inventory-slot ] of my-tags
  let reverse-list reverse forward-list
  let num-tags count my-tags
  ask my-tags
  [ if position my-inventory-slot forward-list + position my-inventory-slot reverse-list != num-tags - 1
    [ set unique-tags other unique-tags ]
  ]
  ask unique-tags
  [ set color red
    set inventoried? true
  ]
end
```

It is very ugly, so someone else's answer would be good. What this does is strips out the my-inventory-values for the relevant tags into a list. It creates two copies of that list, one in normal order and the other reversed. It identifies non-unique values by finding those with a different position for the first appearance in those two lists. If it's not unique, the relevant tag is removed from the unique-tags agentset.

Comment: thank you for your answer. The code above can not be run because `tags with [ my-inventory-slot ] != my-inventory-slot`is not an agentset. I have tried   `ask tags with [[ my-inventory-slot ] != my-inventory-slot]` and Netlogo indicates that `[my-inventory-slot]` must be a literal value.

Comment: you are right, the problem with my code is the context because tags in the ask construct is a variable named my-tags and is defined in the reader context (another agent breed). I am going to update this to the question.

Comment: no, the code was not doing what I wanted. For this reason I have update the code above. The part `ask my-tags...` is into a readers context, in a clause `ask readers [....ask my-tags [....`. The problem is in the filter of my-tags because I have tested as `my-inventory-slot = 5` and works fine.

Comment: In that case, we need more of the code around the procedure that's causing problems. Using `let` should fix the stated NetLogo error that it expects a literal value. Is this still the error you are getting?

Comment: I do not understand. I am doing `ask my-tags [...` and in the square brackets I ask for a tag variable. Besides, if I do `ask my-tags [ my-inventory-slot = 5 ] [...` the code works. Please, may you explain further?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160211/discussion-between-jenb-and-pablo).

Comment: it seems it does not change color to red to the tags with unique value of my-inventory-tags.

Comment: have changed a couple of lines. see if that works please

Comment: I think that now is working right. Thank you very much.

Comment: excellent. I am going to delete some comments that are no longer necessary. You should probably do the same so that this is easier to follow for any future readers

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the question asking any other `my-tags`, like this:

```
let kk my-tags
  ask my-tags [ 
      if not any? other kk with [ my-inventory-slot = [my-inventory-slot] of myself ] [
      set inventoried? true
      set color red 
  ] ]
```

which is short and clear.

Comment: Excellent answer. I knew that there was a cleaner approach, but got bogged down in all the intermediate steps in our discussion. You should unaccent mine and accept yours.

Comment: @JenB I want to give you thanks for your help and time.